# Rspec json tests result with wrong date format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I try to test an Api I am working on. I also get the right response, but the dateformat seems to have changed

from `2018-11-27 18:03:44.000000000 +0000`

to   `2018-11-27T18:03:44.000Z`

```
expected: [{"created_at"=>2018-11-27 18:03:44.000000000 +0000, "email"=>"jennettesaway...UfR7oeVa5.ZaWXce2qtn6Em2oSQuH6Iljqhx61BI7cvE3CG", "updated_at"=>2018-11-27 18:03:44.000000000 +0000}]

got: [{"created_at"=>"2018-11-27T18:03:44.000Z", "email"=>"georgene@champlin.biz...4$JlzdvIUfR7oeVa5.ZaWXce2qtn6Em2oSQuH6Iljqhx61BI7cvE3CG", "updated_at"=>"2018-11-27T18:03:44.000Z"}]
```

Here is the spec

```
RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :request do

   let!(:user) { Fabricate(:user) }
   let(:valid_attributes) { Fabricate.attributes_for :user }
   let(:invalid_attributes) { Fabricate.attributes_for :invalid_user }
    # set headers for authorization
   #let(:headers) { { 'Authorization' => token_generator(user.id) } }
   let(:headers) { valid_headers }

   describe "GET #index" do
    before(:each) do
      #allow(request).to receive(:headers).and_return(headers)
    end

    it "returns a success response" do
      get "/users", params: {}, headers: valid_headers
      expect(json).to eq [user.as_json]
    end
   end
end
```

That is my controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authorize_request, only: :create
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
    render json: @users
  end
end
```

The `json` method

```
def json
  JSON.parse(response.body)
end
```

I never had this issue before. What do I have to change?

Comment: can you try `expect(json).to eq [user.to_json]` - does that work?

Comment: also can you show me how `json` in your test is parsed?

Comment: @Anthony with `to_json` I got weired quotes `"{\"id\":1,\"email\":\"chiekolubowitz@carroll.biz\",\"birthday\":\"2000-11-27\"}`.

I add `json` the method

Comment: the issue is that dates are being serialized and derserialized differently between your controller and test.  This isn't a great test btw - comparing hash objects doesn't offer up much in terms of preventing regressions.

Comment: I know, my approach is more a sanity check than a real life spec. Then it could be that jbuilder is changing the deserialization.

Comment: Your "from" and "to" examples are identical.

Comment: @moveson: changed it, thank you

Comment: It's annoying, that `as_json` converts the datetime format.